# SQL Server trigger with loop for multiple row insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I've created trigger for my database which handles some insertion but when I add multiple values in 1 SQL query it doesn't work:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ConferenceDayTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Conferences]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID INT
    DECLARE @dayC INT
    DECLARE @counter INT

    SET @counter = 1
    SET @ID = (SELECT  IDConference FROM Inserted)
    SET @dayC = (SELECT   DATEDIFF(DAY, start,finish) FROM Inserted)

    WHILE @counter <= @dayC + 1 
    BEGIN
        EXEC AddConferenceDay @Id, @counter
        SET @counter = @counter +1
    END
END
```

For single insertion it works ok. But what should I change/add to make it execute for each row of inserted values?

Comment: Loops in SQL are almost always a terrible idea. Loops inside triggers are like a bad idea squared. Now maybe you can't get around it and you have to do it this way, but I sincerely hope not! PS You need to loop through the rows in `inserted` table, likely with a cursor (another bad idea!)

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot change the stored procedure, then this might be one of the (very few) cases when a cursor comes to the rescue.  Double loops, in fact:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ConferenceDayTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Conferences]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
     DECLARE @ID INT;
     DECLARE @dayC INT;
     DECLARE @counter INT
     SET @counter = 1;

     DECLARE yucky_Cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT IDConference, DATEDIFF(DAY, start,finish) FROM Inserted; 
     OPEN yucky_Cursor; /*Open cursor for reading*/


     FETCH NEXT FROM yucky_Cursor INTO @ID, @dayC;
     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
     BEGIN
         WHILE @counter <= @dayC + 1
         BEGIN
             EXEC AddConferenceDay @Id, @counter;
             SET @counter = @counter + 1;
         END;
         FETCH NEXT FROM yucky_Cursor INTO @ID, @dayC;
     END;

    CLOSE yucky_Cursor;
    DEALLOCATE yucky_Cursor;
END;
```

I suspect there is a way to refactor and get rid of the cursor and use set-based operations.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert more than one record, you need to `cursor/while` to call the `AddConferenceDay` procedure for each record.

But I will suggest you to alter your procedure to accept table type as input parameter. So that more than one `ID` and `dayC` as input to `AddConferenceDay` procedure. It is more efficient than your current approach.

something like this

```
create type udt_Conferences as table (ID int,dayC int)
```

Alter the procedure to use udt_Conferences as input parameter

```
Alter procedure AddConferenceDay (@input udt_Conferences readonly)
as 
begin
/* use @input table type instead of @Id and @counter variables */
end
```

To call the procedure update the trigger with created udt

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ConferenceDayTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Conferences]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
Declare @input udt_Conferences

insert into @input (ID,dayC)
select IDConference,DATEDIFF(DAY, start,finish)  from Inserted
END
```

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to your trigger

AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

```
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @Count int;
    Set @Count=@@ROWCOUNT;
    IF @Count=0
    Return;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for trigger here
```